# Thread usage for optimization

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, delegates

Here is a piece of code in C# which applies an operation over each row of a matrix of doubles (suppose 200x200).

```
For (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
   result = process(row[i]);
   DoSomething(result);
}
```

***Process*** is a *static method* and I have a *Corei5* CPU and *Windows XP* and I'm using *.Net Framework 3.5*. To gain performance, I tried to process each row using a separate thread (using *Asynchronous delegates*). So I rewrote the code as follows:

```
List<Func<double[], double>> myMethodList = new List<Func<double[], double>>();
List<IAsyncResult> myCookieList = new List<IAsyncResult>();
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
   Func<double[], double> myMethod = process;
   IAsyncResult myCookie = myMethod.BeginInvoke(row[i], null, null);
   myMethodList.Add(myMethod);
   myCookieList.Add(myCookie);
}
for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)
{
   result = myMethodList[j].EndInvoke(myCookieList[j]);
   DoSomething(result);
}
```

This code is being called for 1000 matrixes in one run. When I tested, surprisingly I didn't get any performance improvement! So this brought up this question for me that in what cases the multi-threading will be of benefit for performance enhancement and also is my code logical?

Comment: Which Core i5 was it? The number of available threads is limited based on which chip it was. Additionally, I don't think you're going to see a big increase but I'm surprised you say you got no improvement.

Comment: When execution takes more than a second you should be able to use TaskManager to gauge if all cores are being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, your code looks OK. Maybe the CPU isn't the bottleneck.

Can you confirm that `process()` and `DoSomething()` are independent and don't do any I/O or locking for shared resources?

The point here is that you'll have to start measuring.

And of course Fx4 with the TPL makes this kind of thing easier to write and ususally more efficient.

Comment: +1 for TPL, this can be used in .Net 3.5 (it's part of Reactive Extensions).

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve more parallelism (in the result processing, specifically) by calling `BeginInvoke` with an `AsyncCallback` - this will do the result processing in a `ThreadPool` thread, instead of inline as you have it currently.

See the last section of the async programming docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Before you do anything to modify the code, you should profile it to find out where the program is spending its time.

Comment: Are you sure? And do you have a link for that?

Comment: @Henk - other than the one I included in the answer, no.  See the section `Executing a Callback Method When an Asynchronous Call Completes`

Comment: Ah, I see. I think that page states that the callback will be executed on the ThreadPool _as well_, not that execution w/o a callback is inline. I don't think that would make sense.

Comment: @Henk - yes, the implication I intended was that `DoSomething` would instead get executed in the callback function, on the threadpool thread.

Comment: @Steve, agreed, the OP should probably roll the 2 methods into 1. If they are bot independent etc.

Comment: @Henk - yes all of this assumes no "big lock" that makes the whole thing unparallelizable, which seems reasonable given the problem definition

Comment: @Henk @Steve Thanks guys, actually the code over here is a simplified version of the actual code that I'm trying to optimize. So to be sure I checked the "Big Lock" issue; in the original function there is another array of doubles which is being passed to Process (Process(double[], double[])) this second double[] is the same array for all the threads and the values in it are just used and not changed. I thought that might be a lock, but when I wrote a small test application I could see that still multi-threading in my test cause performance improvement.

Comment: @Henk @Steve I did more analysis on the code and I figure most of the time the number of rows is between 30 ~ 40 ... and this whole thing is being called about 150 times. So maybe the issue is that the overload of setting up the threads is more than the simple execution of this 40x200 process. In other words, the bottleneck of the application is really not this funciton. (PS: about the callback, I'm not sure if I can use it because the order of the output is important for me).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is going a little overboard. Look at the loops; for each of 200 iterations, you are creating a new thread to make an asynchronous call. That will result in your process having 201 active threads. There is a law of diminishing returns; at about double the number of threads as the number of "execution units" that the processor has (the number of CPUs, times the number of cores on each CPU, X2 if the cores can be hyper-threaded), your computer will start spending more time scheduling threads than it spends running them. The state-of-the-art servers have 4 quad-core HT CPUs, for about 32 EUs. 200 actively executing threads will make this server break down and cry.

If the order of processing doesn't matter, I would implement a MergeSort-like algorithm; break the array in half, process the left hand, process the right hand. Each "left hand" can be processed by a new thread, but process the "right hand" in the current thread. Then, implement some thread-safe means to limit the thread count to about 1.25 times the number of "execution units"; If the limit has been reached, continue processing linearly without creating a new thread.

Comment: He's not creating 200 threads but queuing 200 jobs on the ThreadPool. The TP will (slowly) create extra threads to process them.

Comment: ... but last I checked, the ThreadPool didn't "intelligently" limit the thread count for its jobs; you have to manually throttle it back to a sane number for your environment, or it will indeed create 200 worker threads if the threads are long-lived enough.

Comment: No, it limits it unintelligently. It holds back by creating at most 1 Thread / 500 msec. The Fx4 TP is (a little) smarter though. Pity the OP didn't post abs running times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't gaining any performance because of the way you are handling the EndInvoke method call. Since you are calling "process" using BeginInvoke, those function calls return immediately so the first loop probably finishes in no time at all. However, EndInvoke blocks until the call for which it is being called is finished processing, which you are still using sequentially. As Steve said, you should use an AsyncCallback so that each completion event is handled on it's own thread.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with the EndInvoke(). Because while we are waiting for the first thread to finish, other threads are being processed too and by the time the first result comes out, other live threads also have generated their results. So the next iterations of the loop are not waiting for the remaining threads because their results are already generated in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you are not seeing much gain because you are not parallelizing the code, yes, you are doing async but that just means that your loop does not wait to calculate to go to the next step. use Parallel.For instead of for loop and see if you see any gain on your multi-core box...

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use async delegates, this would be the way to do it to enure the callbacks happen on a Thread pool thread;

```
        internal static void Do()
    {
        AsyncCallback cb = Complete;

        List<double[]> row = CreateList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Func<double[], double> myMethod = Process;
            myMethod.BeginInvoke(row[i], cb, null);
        }
    }
    static double Process (double[] vals)
    {
       // your implementation
        return randy.NextDouble();
    }
    static void Complete(IAsyncResult token)
    {

        Func<double[], double> callBack = (Func<double[], double>)((AsyncResult)token).AsyncDelegate;
        double res = callBack.EndInvoke(token);

        Console.WriteLine("complete res {0}", res);
        DoSomething(res);


    }
```